# Помогите распарсить json файл на golang

Tags: json, vkontakte-api, golang

Имеется json файл вот такого содержания 
`{"response[{"uid":1,"first_name":"Павел","last_name":"Дуров","sex":2,"city":2,"photo_max_orig":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c836333\/v836333001\/31190\/RMbqDaZJd-0.jpg","verified":1}]}`

как мне в golang получить все данные из него в структуру, что бы я мог обращаться к каждому полю, например: first_name : "Павел"?

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Comment: Примеры из документации не подходят. Первым элементом представлен массив в моем json файле. Не могли бы вы предоставить мне пример кода, если вам не солжно?

Comment: Возможно, `{"response":[...` (добавлены `":`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В документации всё описано.

```
type Body struct {
    Response []Response `json:"response"`
}    

type Response struct {
    UID       int64  `json:"uid"`
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    // ...
}

// ...

b := &Body{}
err := json.Unmarshal(data, b)
fmt.Println(err, b.Response[0].FirstName)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZbdqaPUqBD.

Answer (score 1):

Два отличных сервиса очень помогают

1. https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Даёте ему JSON он выдаёт вам Go структуру. Ваш пример:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "uid": 1,
      "first_name": "\u041f\u0430\u0432\u0435\u043b",
      "last_name": "\u0414\u0443\u0440\u043e\u0432",
      "sex": 2,
      "city": 2,
      "photo_max_orig": "https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c836333\/v836333001\/31190\/RMbqDaZJd-0.jpg",
      "verified": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

выдаёт

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Response []struct {
        UID          int    `json:"uid"`
        FirstName    string `json:"first_name"`
        LastName     string `json:"last_name"`
        Sex          int    `json:"sex"`
        City         int    `json:"city"`
        PhotoMaxOrig string `json:"photo_max_orig"`
        Verified     int    `json:"verified"`
    } `json:"response"`
}
```

Понятное дело уже сами меняете имена полей на то что вам нравится.

2. http://jsonprettyprint.com/

Имя говорит само за себя. Красивый JSON выдаёт. Помогает увидеть структуру так сказать.

Удачи